# mysql not equal operator not working

Tags: mysql, sql, equals

When I try this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sds_posts 
WHERE topic_id = '2439' 
  AND author = ANY (SELECT mid 
                    FROM sds_actions 
                    WHERE whoami = '710' AND type = 'block')
  AND status = '1' 
  AND deleted = '0' 
ORDER BY 
  id ASC 
LIMIT 50
```

it is working correctly.

But I need this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sds_posts 
WHERE topic_id = '2439' 
  AND author <> ANY (SELECT mid 
                    FROM sds_actions 
                    WHERE whoami = '710' AND type = 'block')
  AND status = '1' 
  AND deleted = '0' 
ORDER BY 
  id ASC 
LIMIT 50
```

This time query have to select opposite of first query, but it is just select all author. I tried `!=` and also `NOT IN`, but result is same.

So why? Why does `<>` not work as expected?

Comment: If the "any" works, maybe inverting the inner select would work: `SELECT * FROM sds_posts WHERE topic_id='2439' and author = any (SELECT mid FROM sds_actions WHERE whoami<>'710' OR type<>'block') AND status='1' and deleted='0' ORDER by id ASC LIMIT 50`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that changing

```
and author = any...
to
and NOT author = any...
```

would work...  But if that does not, then I would try doing as a left-join and looking for null.  Since the author is the "mid" from the sds_actions, I would write it as...

```
SELECT 
      sp.* 
   FROM 
      sds_posts sp
         LEFT JOIN sds_actions sa
            on sp.author = sa.mid
           AND sa.whoami = '710'
           AND sa.type = 'block'
   WHERE 
          sp.topic_id = '2439' 
      AND sp.status = '1' 
      AND sp.deleted = '0' 
      AND sa.mid IS NULL
   ORDER by 
      sp.id ASC 
   LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try change `author = any(...)` to `author IN (...)`

and change `author <> any(...)` to `author NOT IN (...)`